# Is there any overhead to declaring a variable within a loop? (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, variable-declaration

I am just wondering if there would be any loss of speed or efficiency if you did something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 100)
{
    int var = 4;
    i++;
}
```

which declares `int var` one hundred times.  It seems to me like there would be, but I'm not sure. would it be more practical/faster to do this instead:

```
int i = 0;
int var;
while(i < 100)
{
    var = 4;
    i++;
}
```

or are they the same, speedwise and efficiency-wise?

Comment: To be clear, the above code does not "declare" var one hundred times.

Comment: @Rabarberski: The referenced question is not an exact duplicate as it does not specify a language. **This question is specific to C++**. But according to the answers posted to your referenced question, the answer depends on the language and possibly the compiler.

Comment: @jason If the first snippet of code does not declare the variable 'var' one hundred times, can you explain what's happening? Does it just declare the variable once and initialize it 100 times? I would've thought that the code declares and initializes the variable 100 times, since everything in the loop is executed 100 times. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declaring variables inside loops, good practice or bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959573/declaring-variables-inside-loops-good-practice-or-bad-practice)

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Stack space for local variables is usually allocated in function scope. So no stack pointer adjustment happens inside the loop, just assigning 4 to `var`. Therefore these two snippets have the same overhead.

Comment: I wish those guys who teach at out college at least knew this basic thing. Once he laughed at me declaring a variable inside a loop and I was wondering what's wrong until he cited performance as the reason not to do so and I was like "WTF!?".

Comment: Are you sure you should be talking about stack space right away. A variable like this could also be in a register.

Comment: @toto A variable like this could also be _nowhere_ – the `var` variable is initialized but never used, so a reasonable optimiser can just remove it completely (except the second snippet **if** the variable was used somewhere after the loop).

Comment: @Mehrdad Afshari a variable in a loop gets its constructor called once per iteration.  EDIT - I see you mentioned this below, but I think it deserves mention in the accepted answer as well.

Answer (score 115):

For primitive types and POD types, it makes no difference.  The compiler will allocate the stack space for the variable at the beginning of the function and deallocate it when the function returns in both cases.

For non-POD class types that have non-trivial constructors, it WILL make a difference -- in that case, putting the variable outside the loop will only call the constructor and destructor once and the assignment operator each iteration, whereas putting it inside the loop will call the constructor and destructor for every iteration of the loop.  Depending on what the class' constructor, destructor, and assignment operator do, this may or may not be desirable.

Comment: This doesn't seem true.  If you use a nonPOD type and assign it in the loop over and over again as in his example, that assignment to a new variable is calling the constructor over and over again, too.

Comment: Correct idea wrong reason. Variable outside the loop. Constructed once, destroyed once but asignment operator applied every iteration. Variable inside the loop. Constructe/Desatructor aplied every iteration but zero assignment operations.

Comment: This is the best answer but these comments are confusing. There's a big difference between calling a constructor and an assignment operator.

Comment: It *is* true if the loop body does the assignment anyway, not just for initialization. And if there's just a body-independent/constant initialization, the optimizer can hoist it.

Comment: @Andrew Grant: Why. Assignment operator is usually defined as copy construct into tmp followed by swap (to be exception safe) followed by destroy tmp. Thus assignment operator is not that different to construction/destroy cycle above. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255612/c-dynamically-allocating-an-array-of-objects/255744#255744 for example of typical assignment operator.

Comment: If construct/destruct are expensive, their total cost is a reasonable upper limit on the cost of the operator=. But the assignment could indeed be cheaper. Also, as we expand this discussion from ints to C++ types, one could generalize 'var=4' as some other operation than 'assign variable from a value of the same type'.

Answer (score 70):

They are both the same, and here's how you can find out, by looking at what the compiler does (even without optimisation set to high):

Look at what the compiler (gcc 4.0) does to your simple examples:

1.c:

```
main(){ int var; while(int i < 100) { var = 4; } }
```

gcc -S 1.c

1.s:

```
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    $0, -16(%ebp)
    jmp L2
L3:
    movl    $4, -12(%ebp)
L2:
    cmpl    $99, -16(%ebp)
    jle L3
    leave
    ret
```

2.c

```
main() { while(int i < 100) { int var = 4; } }
```

gcc -S 2.c

2.s:

```
_main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $24, %esp
        movl    $0, -16(%ebp)
        jmp     L2
L3:
        movl    $4, -12(%ebp)
L2:
        cmpl    $99, -16(%ebp)
        jle     L3
        leave
        ret
```

From these, you can see two things:  firstly, the code is the same in both.

Secondly, the storage for var is allocated outside the loop:

```
         subl    $24, %esp
```

And finally the only thing in the loop is the assignment and condition check:

```
L3:
        movl    $4, -12(%ebp)
L2:
        cmpl    $99, -16(%ebp)
        jle     L3
```

Which is about as efficient as you can be without removing the loop entirely.

Comment: "Which is about as efficient as you can be without removing the loop entirely"  Not quite.  Partially unrolling the loop (doing it say 4 times per pass) would speed it up dramatically.  There are probably many other ways to optimize...  although most modern compilers would probably realize that there's no point in looping at all.  If 'i' was used later, it'd simply set 'i' = 100.

Comment: that's assuming the code changed to incremented 'i' at all...  as is it's just a forever loop.

Comment: As was the Original Post!

Comment: I like answers that back the theory with proof! Nice to see ASM dump backing up the theory of being equal codes. +1

Comment: Sorry, but how did you ACTUALLY produce your results when the code you have provided above does not have an increment statement to the variable `i`? Are modern compilers that intelligent that they can determine when one wishes to increment forward or backwards and by how much on each iteration?

Comment: I actually produced the results by generating the machine code for each version.  No need to run it.

Comment: @Nicholas Hamilton
You are correct in your evaluation that since i doesn't increment, it will infinite loop forever.  However, since we are not actually running the code, we don't care if it ever actually finishes.  We just print the assembly the compile produces and leave it there.

Comment: `while(int i < 100)` doesn't compile even with `-std=gnu89`.  https://godbolt.org/z/zcEWr1WPE .  But yeah, even in a debug build, whatever you did compile shows GCC doesn't futz with the stack for each loop iteration, as expected.

Answer (score 14):

These days it is better to declare it inside the loop unless it is a constant as the compiler will be able to better optimize the code (reducing variable scope).

EDIT: This answer is mostly obsolete now. With the rise of post-classical compilers, the cases where the compiler can't figure it out are getting rare. I can still construct them but most people would classify the construction as bad code.

Comment: I doubt it will affect optimization -- if the compiler performs any sort of data flow analysis, it can figure out that it's not being modified outside the loop, so it should produce the same optimized code in both cases.

Comment: It won't figure it out if you have two different loops using the same temp variable name though.

Answer (score 11):

Most modern compilers will optimize this for you.  That being said I would use your first example as I find it more readable.

Comment: I don't really count it as an optimization. Since they are local variables, the stack space is just allocated at the beginning of the function. There's no real "creation" involved to harm performance (unless a constructor is being called, which is completely another story).

Comment: You are right, "optimization" is the wrong word but I am at a loss for a better one.

Comment: problem is that such an optimizer will use live range analysis, and both variables are rather dead.

Comment: How about "the compiler won't see any difference between them once it does the data flow analysis". Personally I prefer that the scope of a variable should be confined to where it is used, not for efficiency but for clarity.

Answer (score 9):

For a built-in type there will likely be no difference between the 2 styles (probably right down to the generated code).

However, if the variable is a class with a non-trivial constructor/destructor there could well be a major difference in runtime cost. I'd generally scope the variable to inside the loop (to keep the scope as small as possible), but if that turns out to have a perf impact I'd look to moving the class variable outside the loop's scope.  However, doing that needs some additional analysis as the semantics of the ode path may change, so this can only be done if the sematics permit it.

An RAII class might need this behavior. For example, a class that manages file access lifetime might need to be created and destroyed on each loop iteration to manage the file access properly.

Suppose you have a `LockMgr` class that acquires a critical section when it's constructed and releases it when destroyed:

```
while (i< 100) {
    LockMgr lock( myCriticalSection); // acquires a critical section at start of
                                      //    each loop iteration

    // do stuff...

}   // critical section is released at end of each loop iteration
```

is quite different from:

```
LockMgr lock( myCriticalSection);
while (i< 100) {

    // do stuff...

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Both loops have the same efficiency. They will both take an infinite amount of time :) It may be a good idea to increment i inside the loops.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to address space efficiency - that's ok - 2 ints for both.

It just seems odd to me that programmers are missing the forest for the tree -- all these suggestions about some code that doesn't terminate.

Comment: It's OK if they don't terminate. Neither one of them is called. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I once ran some perfomance tests, and to my surprise, found that case 1 was actually faster!  I suppose this may be because declaring the variable inside the loop reduces its scope, so it gets free'd earlier.  However, that was a long time ago, on a very old compiler.  Im sure modern compilers do a better job of optimizing away the diferences, but it still doesn't hurt to keep your variable scope as short as possible.

Comment: The difference comes probably from the difference in scope. The smaller the scope the more likely the compiler is able to eliminate serialization of the variable. In the small loop scope, the variable was likely put in a register and not saved on the stack frame. If you call a function in the loop, or dereference a pointer the compiler doesn't really know where it points to, it will spill the loop variable if it is in function scope (the pointer might contain `&i`).

Comment: Please post your setup and results.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int test;
        if(i == 0)
            test = 100;
        printf("%d\n", test);
    }
}
```

Code above always prints 100 10 times which means local variable inside loop is only allocated once per each function call.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure is to time them. But the difference, if there is one, will be microscopic, so you will need a mighty big timing loop.

More to the point, the first one is better style because it initializes the variable var, while the other one leaves it uninitialized. This and the guideline that one should define variables as near to their point of use as possible, means that the first form should normally be preferred.

Comment: "The only way to be sure is to time them." -1 untrue. Sorry but another post proved this wrong by comparing the generated machine language and finding it essentially identical.  I don't have any problem with your answer in general, but isn't wrong what the -1 is for?

Comment: Examining emitted code is certainly useful, and in a simple case like this may be sufficient. However, in more complex cases issues such as locality of reference rear their head, and these can only be tested by timing the execution.

Answer (score -1):

With only two variables, the compiler will likely be assign a register for both. These registers are there anyway, so this doesn't take time. There are 2 register write and one register read instruction in either case.

Answer (score -1):

I think that most answers are missing a major point to consider which is: "Is it clear" and obviously by all the discussion the fact is; no it is not.
I'd suggest in most loop code the efficiency is pretty much a non-issue (unless you calculating for a mars lander), so really the only question is what looks more sensible and readable & maintainable - in this case I'd recommend declaring the variable up front & outside the loop - this simply makes it clearer. Then people like you & I would not even bother to waste time checking online to see if it's valid or not.

Answer (score -6):

thats not true 
there is overhead however its neglect able overhead.

Even though probably they will end up at same place on stack It still assigns it.
It will assign memory location on stack for that int and then free it at the end of }. Not in heap free sense in sense it will move sp (stack pointer) by 1. 
And in your case considering it only has one local variable it will just simply equate fp(frame pointer) and sp

Short answer would be: DONT CARE EITHER WAY WORKS ALMOST THE SAME.

But try reading more on how stack is organized. My undergrad school had pretty good lectures on that
If you wanna read more check here
http://www.cs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/classes/cs360/360/notes/Assembler1/lecture.html

Comment: Again, -1 untrue.  Read the post that looked at the assembly.

Comment: nope you are wrong.
look at the assembler code generated with that code