# Is it problematic to declare variables in the main loop of a OpenGL program?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Following some tutorials of OpenGL I noticed some of them declare some variables like transform matrices and uniform locations on the main loop of the program. From my point of view I thought it would be a bad thing because it would allocate memory for the variables for each loop.

Is this a good thing to do? Why should I calculate the location of a uniform in the shaders very loop if the location won't change?

For example, a statement like this in [this code](http://www.learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=lighting/colors_scene) `GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(lightingShader.Program, "model");` will get the same value every loop, why should I use this inside the loop then?

Comment: I think, this is a valid question in the context of OpenGL. It is starkly different from the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959573/declaring-variables-inside-loops-good-practice-or-bad-practice-2-parter which is very generic in scope, and in this case has no similarity at all with the asked question.

Comment: The other question helped me understand somethings related to the topic, but my question is indeed what should I do in the context of OpenGL.

Comment: You're right when you say, `glGetUniformLocation` will return the same value every loop, unless the properties of the drawable/mesh get changed resulting in a change in the shader that you use for it. So you can also choose to only do it when such a case happens. But for that you might need to handle a lot of cases in a lot of places depending of the code flow/architecture you've for yourself.

Comment: So, if I'm sure that the mesh doesn't change through the loop, I can guarantee that I can call `glGetUniformLocation()` outside the loop then? What changes in the mesh could change the uniform location? (should I ask a new question for this one?)

Comment: Let's say you apply a filter/texture on the mesh. For that the shader code will be different. It'll invariably have a few more uniforms. Hence the uniform locations might get changed. So yes, you can do it outside the loop, once per lifecycle of the GL context.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you!