# Why is it possible to define a variable inside a loop in C?

Tags: c, loops, redefinition

Why doesn't this code give a redefinition error:

```
int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        int number = 5;
    }
}
```

while this code does:

```
int main(void)
{
    int number = 5;
    int number = 5;
}
```

Comment: *"Why is it possible to define a variable inside a loop in C?"* - Because it's a very practical thing to do.

Comment: Somebody asked this very question about C++. The accepted answer has a nice illustration with functions, of the same principle https://stackoverflow.com/q/66124034/817643

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code, the scope of `number` begins when execution reaches the opening of the for loop and ends when execution reaches the closing of the for loop. In this case, the body of the for loop is executed two times, and `number` is created and destroyed two times, and has two disjoint scopes. In the second code, the scope aren't disjoint as previous `number` is still persisting it's lifetime when the second one is defined, and they are in the same scope, so it's a re-definition error.

Comment: Lifetime is not actually the issue here; scope is.

Comment: So it is a different scope in each iteration? I wasn't sure so I did not want to say that and technically sound incorrect so I used "lifetime".

Comment: Scope does not have anything to do with program execution, including iterations of loops. Scope is **where** in program source code an identifier is visible. Lifetime is **when** during program execution an object exists. Essentially, one identifier cannot refer to two different things in one scope. A declaration in an inner scope is allowed to hide a declaration of the same identifier in an outer scope, but that does not work within the same scope.

Comment: So, can I think of `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {int number = 5; printf("Hello World);}` as the same thing with `{int number = 5; printf("Hello World");} {int number = 5; printf("Hello World");}` ?

Comment: @kooru_hi Yes I think you can

Answer (score 2):

Redfinition errors are a compile-time issue, not a runtime issue.  You don’t get a redefinition error in the loop because you only have one declaration for `number` within that scope.

In the second snippet you have two declarations for `number` within the same scope, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, creating a variable inside a loop will make the variable's scope stay in this very loop. "number" does not exist outside of your loop.