# C++: potential memory leak in linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory-leaks, new-operator

I'm writing a class of linked list, I feel that for the member function that used to delete specific element might cause the memory leak. The code is below.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

class linked_list
{
private:
    node *head,*tail;
public:
    linked_list()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    void add_node(int n)
    {
        node *tmp = new node;
        tmp->data = n;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
        
    }
    void DelElem(int locat)
    {
        int j{1};
        node* tmp = new node;     
        if (locat == 1)
        {      
            tmp  = head->next;
            head = tmp;
            delete tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            node* n = head;
            while (j < locat - 1)
            {
                n = n->next;
                j++;
            }
            tmp = n->next;
            n->next = tmp->next;
            delete tmp; 
        } 
    }
```

For function 'DelElem', I firstly created a pointer tmp by new operator. However, I assign different address for it which means I lost the original one at the initialization.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why are you using new in a function that removes nodes? You should never do so.

Comment: ***I firstly created a pointer tmp by new operator*** This is wrong. You don't use new to create a pointer. You use new to allocate a new node. `node* tmp;` creates a pointer. c++ is not a language where you use new to create every variable.

Comment: ***However, I assign different address for it which means I lost the original one at the initialization.*** That is correct, you are creating a memory leak with the unnecessary `new` which allocates a new node.

Comment: *"How can I fix this problem?"* -- by not creating the problem in the first place. You correctly identified the problem, so get rid of it.

Comment: Food for thought: [Declaring variables inside loops, good practice or bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959573/declaring-variables-inside-loops-good-practice-or-bad-practice) (The principles apply to `if` statements as well as to loops.)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hi, I just saw the answer and I accepted yours. sry bro.

Comment: @NicolasH No worries :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your instance of code, I have corrected that:-

1. As pointed by others, you are not required to use `new` keyword to declare a pointer.
2. When one tries to delete the first node of the linked list, then according to your code, it will delete the second node, because of the following

   ```
   tmp  = head->next;
   head = tmp;
   delete tmp;
   ```

   Here, `tmp` is initially pointing to second node,because `head->next` refers to 2nd node. So instead of that, it should have been like this:-

   ```
   tmp = head;
   head = head->next;
   delete tmp;
   ```

   Now, `tmp` will point to 1st node, in second line, `head` will point to 2nd node, and then the first node, pointed by `tmp` gets deleted.

Here is the corrected version of code:-

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
};

class linked_list {
private:
    node *head, *tail;

public:
    linked_list()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    void add_node(int n)
    {
        node* tmp = new node;
        tmp->data = n;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }
    void DelElem(int locat)
    {
        int j{ 1 };
        node* tmp;
        if (locat == 1) {
            tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        else {
            node* n = head;
            while (j < (locat - 1)) {
                n = n->next;
                j++;
            }
            tmp = n->next;
            n->next = tmp->next;
            cout << tmp->data;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
};
```