# c++ declararion variables in for loop

Tags: c++

Question is about variables inside the loop. How does it works?
Similar questions:
[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982963/is-there-any-overhead-to-declaring-a-variable-within-a-loop-c)
[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407255/difference-between-declaring-variables-before-or-in-loop)

code:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {
   vector<int> vint;
   vint.push_back(i);
   cout << "vecor size is: " << vint.size() << endl;
   for ( j = 0 ; j < vint.size() ; j++ ) {
       cout << "vint[" << j << "] = " << vint[j] << endl;
   }
}
```

above code gives next output:

```
vecor size is: 1   
vint[0] = 0
vecor size is: 1
vint[0] = 1
vecor size is: 1
vint[0] = 2
```

It looks like that in the end of each iteration method sdt::vector::erase is called or somehow vint becomes again empty. How does it work, and how did you figure out it? thank you!

UPDATE:
If I want different vector in each iteration what is better:
declare vint in the loop
or declare it before the loop and use clear() in the end of the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in the statement of the for-loop are constructed and destructed in each iteration. In your particular case this would involve memory allocation and deallocation for each iteration. If you need a different vector each iteration you'd still be best off declaring it prior to the loop (or in the loop's initialization) and `clear()`ing it at the end of the loop (or in the loop's advance).

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `vint` **inside** the loop, so its lifetime is precisely **one** iteration.  On each iteration, a fresh `vector` is constructed, and the end of each iteration, its destructor is called.

Try moving the declaration of `vint` to outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`vint` is cleared (the whole thing, not just the items) from the stack on each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: That's true. But it's not a very helpful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are re-declaring `vint` each time at the beginning of the inner loop. Hence the weird output.
Use this instead :

```
vector<int> vint;
for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {

   vint.push_back(i);
   cout << "vecor size is: " << vint.size() << endl;
   for ( j = 0 ; j < vint.size() ; j++ ) {
       cout << "vint[" << j << "] = " << vint[j] << endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time when outer loop iterates  it initializes vint due to which its size remain same.

```
  for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {
       vector<int> vint;           // vint Initialization
       vint.push_back(i);
       cout << "vecor size is: " << vint.size() << endl;
       for ( j = 0 ; j < vint.size() ; j++ ) {
           cout << "vint[" << j << "] = " << vint[j] << endl;
       }
    }
```

if you write like this then it would contain more values in inner loop

```
 vector<int> vint;           // vint Initialization
 for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {

           vint.push_back(i);
           cout << "vecor size is: " << vint.size() << endl;
           for ( j = 0 ; j < vint.size() ; j++ ) {
               cout << "vint[" << j << "] = " << vint[j] << endl;
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> vint;
```

is being executed every time in outer loop so you get only one element on every iteration