# C# which is right or better expression?

Tags: c#

```
DateTime theMonth = DateTime.Now;
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
     string curMonth = theMonth.AddMonths(-i).ToString("MM/yyyy");
}
```

Or,

```
DateTime theMonth = DateTime.Now;
string curMonth;
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
     curMonth = theMonth.AddMonths(-i).ToString("MM/yyyy");
}
```

which is right or better expression? Or same?

Comment: Neither of them does anything noticeable at the moment...

Comment: Neither one makes any sense.  Why is there a loop?

Comment: @recursive sorry I changed code, my question is, is it OK to define variable in loop?

Comment: One notion of "better" is to use the smallest scope possible for any given variable.  So, while this code snippet is too short for real judgment, according to a theory of minimal scope, declaring the variable inside the loop is preferable.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/for-foreach might be useful info.

Comment: Also another SO answer on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982963/is-there-any-overhead-to-declaring-a-variable-within-a-loop-c/983271#983271

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
DateTime theMonth = DateTime.Now;
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
     string curMonth = theMonth.AddMonths(-i).ToString("MM/yyyy");
}
```

if you're only going to be using `curMonth` inside the loop, AND you don't need its value to persist across loop iterations.

Use

```
DateTime theMonth = DateTime.Now;
string curMonth;
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
     curMonth = theMonth.AddMonths(-i).ToString("MM/yyyy");
}
```

if you're planning on using `curMonth` after your loop code has finished executing, or you need the value to hold its value between iterations.

Answer (score 0):

> @recursive sorry I changed code, my question is, is it OK to define variable in loop?

Of course it is ok to define variables in a loop. Just notice that the content of this variable will be lost everytime the loop reaches the end "}". So your initial question can't be answered here because there is no better expression. It depends on your requirements