# Will this declaration of local variables atually repeat many times?

Tags: c++, variables

I heard that we should make variables as local as possible, I agree. Consider this code:

```
int main()  {
    for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i)    {
        int temp;
        std::cin >> temp;
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    }
    return 0
}
```

`temp` is the local variable of the `for` loop. However, I am afraid that `temp` is declared at every loop, therefore make the program run slower. Would it be better to avoid this case and declare the `temp` outside the `for` loop?

```
int main()  {
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i)    {
        std::cin >> temp;
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference on speed, except that you put `temp` on the stack for longer time in the latter case. I'd prefer the first one.

Comment: Who gives a hoot if it's slower? Using C++ made your program slower, you should be programming hand-tuned assembly!

Comment: @GManNickG That's my personal understanding, I thought with a more step `declaration` will make the program run slower.

Comment: That's a question best answered with a benchmark.

Comment: @buzhidao: I was being facetious. You should focus on readability over performance. Even if this variable location made things slower, it makes things easier to read so it's worth it. Your program doesn't need to be as fast as possible, it just needs to be fast enough. After your program isn't fast enough, use a profiler to figure out where it's slow. Guaranteed it's not at this line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That doesn't make any difference on speed, except that you put `temp` on the stack for longer time in the latter case.

I'd prefer the first one, as it is a good practice to *minimize* the scope of variables wherever possible.

Comment: However will it declare temp every time?

Comment: @buzhidao: Yes, *semantically*.

Comment: @buzhidao: Found a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982963/is-there-any-overhead-to-declaring-a-variable-within-a-loop-c), which explains it in other ways. Have a look at them.

Comment: Thanks, I was avoiding coding as the first one before, now I know its OK to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, always write for clarity first and speed second.  Secondly, don't comprise clarity for speed until you have measurements to show it helps.

*Declaring* a variable is a thing that happens at compile time.  What happens at run-time is *initialization*, and yes, if you declare `temp` inside the loop, it will be initialized every time through the loop.  This can matter if `temp` is expensive to initialize.  However in the case of an int without an initializer, the cost is *zero*; the value is left indeterminate.

Comment: @krzaq: Why doesn't  "However in the case of an int without an initializer, the cost is zero; the value is left indeterminate." cover that?  (Actually there's nothing to stop a compiler initializing a default-initialized aggregate to some well know value.)

Comment: It does. I can only blame tiredness, sorry.

Comment: Phew!  My first assumption is always that my answer is unclear.

Comment: Well, if I were to nit-pick on anything it'd be the *always*. Surely you can come up with an example of a hot code that has to be as fast as possible, at any cost ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's really a matter of personal preference. Declaring `temp` inside the for loop won't make a difference in speed.