# Freeing in the destructor is causing a memory leak

Tags: c++

I have to write a stack class template using arrays in C++ for my assignment.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/m1948c5f5) is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type>
class Stack {
private:
  int top;
  Type items[];
public:
  Stack()  { top = -1; };
  ~Stack() { delete[] items; };
  void push(Type);
  bool isEmpty() const;
  Type pop();
  Type peek() const;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Stack<double> st;
  return 0;
}

template<typename Type>
void Stack<Type>::push(Type item) {
  top++;
  if(top == sizeof(items) / sizeof(Type)) {
    Type buff[] = new Type[top];
    std::copy(items,items+top,buff);
    delete[] items;
    items = new Type[2*top];
    std::copy(buff,buff+top,items);
    delete[] buff;
  }
  items[top] = item;
}

template<typename Type>
bool Stack<Type>::isEmpty() const {
  return top == -1 ? true : false;
}

template<typename Type>
Type Stack<Type>::pop() {
  //TODO
  return items[top--];
}

template<typename Type>
Type Stack<Type>::peek() const{
  //TODO
  return items[top-1];
}
```

It compiled fine using "`g++ -Wall`", however when I run the program, I got this error:

> *** glibc detected *** `./lab3: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff41a3cdf8`

After trying out a bit with GDB, I found out the error arose from the line:

```
'free[] items' in the destructor.
```

I don't understand why freeing an array results in a memory leak? Any clues?

Comment: Next time can you please have the code on stackoverflow so when someone in a few months time finds the topic they can see the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't new'd items, so you can't delete it in the destructor. Assuming you require 'Stack' to be a dynamically sized class then the items array must be dynamically allocated in which case the declaration for items should be

```
Type *items;    (as hacker mentions above)
```

and the constructor should call 'items = new Type[ARRAY_SIZE]' to allocate the memory, or at the very least initially assign the 'items' pointer to NULL.

Edit based on comments -

To complete and secure the memory allocation responsibilities for this class you should also include a copy constructor and an assignment operator which allocates new memory and copies the values stored in items to the new object. This avoids the pointer simply being copied by the compiler generated copy constructor or assignment operator which would lead to multiple objects pointing to the same dynamically allocated memory. Upon destruction of the first of these objects this memory will be deleted. Further use of the now deleted memory by the other objects which share the pointer would be likely to result in a crash.

Rather than adding code here I refer you to the code in Martin's answer for  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255612/c-dynamically-allocating-an-array-of-objects/255744#255744).

Comment: You need to finish this article. It is not safe as currently written. If you use new in the constructor and delete in the destructor you MUST also define the copy constructor and assignment operator otherwise a copy of the obejct will cause a double delete. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255612/c-dynamically-allocating-an-array-of-objects/255744#255744

Comment: PS. It would be safer to advice the OP to use a vector.

Comment: @Martin York - in that case, why not use `std::stack`? This is apparently a learning exercise, so your first comment is probably more appropriate here: all the "non-trivial destructor" methods must be either defined or hidden in this class.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I appreciate that a vector may be more appropriate in most situations and would be my preference here rather than an array of 'items' but an array would be useful for performance/code size critical applications. Of course if that were the situation you'd also wonder why a template based Stack class was being used at all... :P  It is also implied (but not 100% clear) from the question that the exercise is to create a Stack class using arrays.

Answer (score 6):

You should only `delete[]` what you have explicitly allocated with `new[]`. Your `items` member is not a dynamically allocated array, so you must not free it as if it were.

On the other hand, you have

```
Type items[];
```

which doesn't actually allocate any space in your object instances for the stack.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that's a memory leak! It's a crash occurring because you deleted a non-heap object.

Comment: Exactly. The Stack class instance is an automatic variable and then its destructor tries to delete[] the member variable array.

Answer (score 2):

*items* is a pointer to Type. This pointer must be initialised 
before it is used (it is a [wild pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) as it is). That 
is why your program crashes. That it happens in the 
destructor is a coincidence. It could just as well have 
happened earlier. E.g. in push() memory is overwritten in the 
location that *items* happens to point to.

You need to allocate memory for a number of elements. See below.

You already have the logic for the dynamic growth of the 
array in place. But an array in C++ does not know its size 
(it is just a pointer of some type). You need to keep track 
of the current capacity/size. Thus instead of

```
sizeof(items)
```

define a new member to hold the current capacity.

E.g.:

int capacity;

and in the constructor:

```
capacity = 100;
items = new Type[capacity];
```

The last line allocates a number of elements and is the main solution to your problem.

And in push():

```
if (top == capacity / sizeof(Type)) {
```

---

The logic for reallocation will need to change. E.g.:

```
capacity *= 2;
items = new Type[capacity];
```

instead of
    items = new Type[2*top];

I have just sketched out a solution here. Yon can fill in the details.

---

**Note**: you have only one instance of Stack in your program; body of main() is:

```
Stack<double> st;
```

If you instead were to assign one instance of Stack to another instance, e.g.

```
{
   Stack<double> st;
   Stack<double> st2 = st; //Copy constructor will be invoked for st2. If not defined the compiler generated copy constructor will do a copy of the pointer value.
   Stack<double> st3;
   st3 = st; //Assignment operator will be invoked for st3. If not defined the compiler generated assignment operator will do a copy of the pointer value.
}
```

then the copy constructor (to work for st2) and the 
assignment operator (to work for st3) for Stack must be 
defined properly (make a copy of the referenced member 
*items*). Otherwise a double or triple delete in the destructor and 
undefined behavior (e.g. a crash) will be the result when 
st, st2 and st3 goes out of scope at the close brace.

Comment: "But an array in C++ does not know its size"  correct but only for dynamic (heap) arrays, with a stack array (size fixed at compile time), you can work out how big an array is using  (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])) 
Generally though, don't bother, use a std::vector ( or boost::array if you need it on the stack) instead.

Comment: Also you don't explain the issues with copy construction and assignment operators. Without these your answer is dangerous at best. Best advice is to use std::vector.

Comment: @Martin York: thanks for pointing that out. I have now added a section to my answer to explain the issues.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I've seen is that you're likely to mean `Type *items`, not `Type items[]`.

And then you don't want to (can't) use `sizeof` on the dynamically allocated data.