# Dynamic memory resize char array

Tags: c++, c++14, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying resize a char array, i've followed:
[Resizing a char[] at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354900/resizing-a-char-at-run-time)

then:

i've done something like this:

```
// this crashes in runtime:

const long SIZE_X = 1048576;

char* Buffsz = new char(sizeof(char));

for(int i = 0; i < (SIZE_X - 2); i++)
{
    Buffsz[i] = 'a';
    if(realloc(Buffsz, sizeof(char) * i) == NULL) // autoallocate memory
        cout << "Failled to reallocate memory!" << endl;
}
```

but if I do:

```
// this works without problems.
const long SIZE_X = 1048576;

char* ABuffsz = new char[SIZE_X];

for(int i = 0; i < (SIZE_X - 2); i++)
{
    ABuffsz[i] = 'a';
}

cout << "End success! len: " << strlen(ABuffsz) << endl;
```

For me this should be fine, but if it's wrong, how i can auto allocate memory?

P.S: I know about of use `std::vector` but i want use this if its possible.

Comment: realloc allocates a *new* block. But in your code Buffsz keeps pointing to the old block that just got freed. Also, your code allocates one char, writes to the first element, reallocates it to *zero* chars, writes to the second element (that doesn't exist), reallocates to one char, writes to the third element (that doesn't exist), ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`realloc()` is used to resize C-style arrays that were allocated with `malloc()`. `realloc()` cannot be used in C++ code, to resize C++ objects that were instantiated in dynamic scope with `new`.

There is no equivalent for `realloc()` in C++. In C++, the simplest way to resize an existing array is: a new array must be constructed in dynamic scope with `new []`, the values from the existing array `std::copy`-ed to the new array, and then the old array `delete[]`-ed.

That's a lot of work. This will involve a lot of unnecessary default-construction and copy-assignment (and if your classes do not have default constructors, you're stuck). Using placement-new and manual copy/move constructors it is possible to optimize some of this work. But it is a lot of work. And that's why you should use `std::vector`. It does all this for you, and it does this correctly.

There's nothing wrong with using `new` and `delete` yourself, as you would like to do. This is good learning experience, in order to gain some understanding how to properly manage dynamically-scoped objects. Fully understanding how low level dynamic scoping works is valuable knowledge to have. However, at some point all of this gets real old, and non-trivial tasks, involving dynamically-scoped objects, become tedious and error prone, and a major time-burner.

At that point, the only way to retain what's left of one's sanity is to start using C++ library containers, which take care of all the grunge work for you. In conclusion: use `std::vector`, and let it do all this work for you.

Comment: I did not know about that, i thought it was possible, i haven't choice but to use `std::vector`. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `realloc()` on pointer allocated memory with `new` operator. You could use this function to resize a pointer

```
char* Resize(char*& old,long int length,long int resize_to)
{
    char* new_ptr;
    new_ptr = new char[ resize_to ];
    long int least = ( length < resize_to ) ? length : resize_to;
    for(long int i = 0;i < least ; ++i)
        new_ptr [i] = old[i];
    delete [] old;
    old = nullptr;
    return new_ptr;
}
```

This Might work and don't forget to `delete[]` that reallocated pointer after it is no longer needed or you'll have to worry about a memory leak

Though you might want to us `std::string` or `std::vector` or create your own dynamically expanding Stack class.

Answer (score 1):

To use `realloc` the memory must have been allocated with `malloc` or other function in that family.

The simplest way to deal with strings of `char` in C++ is to use `std::string`.