# Storing objects in STL vector - minimal set of methods

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor, rule-of-three

What is "minimal framework" (necessary methods) of complex object (with explicitly malloced internal data), which I want to store in STL container, e.g. `<vector>`?

For my assumptions (example of complex object Doit):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class Doit {
    private:
        char *a;
    public:
        Doit(){a=(char*)malloc(10);}
        ~Doit(){free(a);}
};

int main(){
    vector<Doit> v(10);
}
```

gives

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0804b008 ***
Aborted
```

and in valgrind:

```
malloc/free: 2 allocs, 12 frees, 50 bytes allocated.
```

UPDATE:

Minimal methods for such object are: (based on sbi answer)

```
class DoIt{
    private:
        char *a;
    public:
        DoIt() { a=new char[10]; }
        ~DoIt() { delete[] a; }
        DoIt(const DoIt& rhs) { a=new char[10]; std::copy(rhs.a,rhs.a+10,a); }
        DoIt& operator=(const DoIt& rhs) { DoIt tmp(rhs); swap(tmp); return *this;}
        void swap(DoIt& rhs) { std::swap(a,rhs.a); }
};
```

Thanks, sbi, https://stackoverflow.com/users/140719/sbi

Comment: You really should use vectors of <char> instead of doing your own mallocs.  This is C++ after all.

Comment: no. but I really need a pointer inside a object, which is malloced.

Comment: @Joe, My code a but bigger, and I need to store objects in STL containers. This is just easy sample of such code. Real objects have several pointers and ints inside.

Comment: @osgx, why insist on malloc?  Is there a good reason to not use new?

Comment: Problem is not with malloc or vector. Problem is on implementing right methods for using class as STL payload.

Comment: @osgx: No, the memory doesn't need to be malloced. It should be newed. And, actually, Joe is right and this should be hidden inside a `std::vector`.

Comment: the difference between new and malloc is for other question. Thanks.

Comment: Of course this would be a lot simpler if you did not use C inside C++. Do __NOT__ dynamically allocate memory unless you really need to (and you don't). Use a std::vecrtor<char>. You can initiallise it in the constructor to have 10 characters then the rest of the code is unchanged.

Comment: @Martin York, the original Object is container (STL-like, but written from scratch) itself and it uses `::operator new` for creating array of other objects. The `char* ` and malloc used here only **for example**.

Comment: @Martin York, here malloc and free was very useful to debug my stl-like container. With them I can easy check (with any memory leak detector), if I have balanced constructors and destructors.

Comment: See here for a more detailed explanation of sbi response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255612/c-dynamically-allocating-an-array-of-objects/255744#255744

Comment: SBI solution to this problem is fine for char. But if the design is naively used hold another type (i.e. keep char* a, but use placement new put objects into the buffer) has a flaw. You need to take into account the stored types copy constructor failing and tidy up correctly.

Comment: @Martin York, I actually had the problem with complex objects, stored within my container, but solved it with element-by-element copying. How must I handle the throw from objects's copy constructor inside copy constructor of container?

Comment: @osgx: Yes. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508284/c-copy-constructor-and-shallow-copy/2509272#2509272

Comment: @Martin: Actually, looking at my answer now, I think the biggest mistake I made was not mentioning that the `DoIt` class should not hold raw dynamic arrays at all. Doing elaborate things like using placement `new` to put other objects into a char array should not even be attempted except when you know exactly what you do. (If you fail to obey the Rule of Three it's unlikely you know enough to attempt this.)

Comment: @sbi: Absolutely. PS. I always call it the rule of four. There are four auto generated methods that need to be implemented correctly.

Comment: @Martin, re _Rule of Four:_ I'd rather keep going with _Rule of Three_. There are many cases where you need a def ctor, but none of the other three.

Comment: @sbi: Yes in most cases its just Constructor. But when you have pointers you better have defined all four compiler generated methods otherwise you will be in trouble.  :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that Charles has [answered your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501171/storing-objects-in-stl-vector-minimal-set-of-methods/2501298#2501298) perfectly.

Anyway, as per the [*Rule of Three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), your class, having a destructor, should have a copy constructor and an assignment operator, too.

Here's how I would do it:

```
class Doit {
    private:
        char *a;
    public:
        Doit()                   : a(new char[10]) {}
        ~Doit()                    {delete[] a;}
        DoIt(const DoIt& rhs)    : a(new char[10]) {std::copy(rhs.a,rhs.a+10,a);}
        void swap(DoIt& rhs)       {std::swap(a,rhs.a);}
        DoIt& operator=(DoIt rhs)  {swap(rhs); return *this;}
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of copy constructor and assignment operator for my case?

Comment: I think you're missing a colon after the Doit() constructor

Comment: @AshleysBrain, nope Doit() a(new char[10]) {} seems perfectly legal to me. If it was without the {} then I would agree with you.

Comment: @Konrad: `Doit() a(new char[10]) {}` certainly missed a `:`. I fixed this.

Comment: @sbi, not to nit-pick (but I will anyway), but shouldn't operator= be implemented as `DoIt tmp(rhs); swap(tmp); return *this;`

Comment: Not `Doit() : a(new char[10] () ) { }` ?

Comment: @Glen, please, don't blame sbi. He showed me an idea, and this code was written in the answer form without compiling. But I get the idea, and typos are fixed in question update.

Comment: @osgx, no one's blaming anyone for anything.  Clarifications like this are designed to help the person who asked the question, in this case you, get the best possible answer.

Comment: @MSalters: What would this bring? You'd initialize the characters which are likely to be overwritten anyway. However, all this would be moot when `std::vector` would have been used - as would be appropriate for this.

Answer (score 6):

All types that you use must be `CopyConstructible` and `Assignable`.

`CopyConstructible` for a type `T` means that if `t` is a `T` or a `const T` then the expression `T(t)` must produce an equivalent `T` to the original `t`; t.~T() must be valid (accessible destructor); and `&t` must give the address of `t` as a `[const] T*`.

`Assignable` means that for a `T`, `t` and a `T` value `u`, the expression `t = u` must make `t` equivalent to `u` and be of type `T&`.

Note that all these requirements are met by simple built-in types and POD-structs. If you do anything non-trivial in a destructor or constructor you must ensure that the copy constructor and copy assignment operator preserver the equivalence semantics.

Comment: Can you provide a link to table of: which Concepts (Assignable, CopyConstructible, others?) are required for different STL containers (vector/map/priority_queue/hash/etc) to store non-trivial object in them.

Comment: They're not "Concepts", they are type _requirements_ and you can find them in [the standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).

Answer (score 0):

All `vector` requires is that the object is "assignable", which means that it needs an copy-constructor, destructor, and assignment operator, which are all generated by default if you don't supply them yourself.

As sbi says, if you need one of those functions then you probably need them all. In your case, you'll need to also provide a copy constructor and assignment operator to avoid heap corruption.