# Where is the member array located?

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    char array[10];
};

int main()
{
    MyClass *p = new MyClass;
...
}
```

As far as I understand - new allocates the object on the heap.
But also, the array is allocated on the stack (no new operator).

So, is the array allocated on heap (because the object is at the heap) or on the program stack?

Comment: @George They mean the free-store

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class members and explicit stack/heap allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836591/class-members-and-explicit-stack-heap-allocation), or [Are the members of a heap allocated class automatically allocated in the heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826722/c-are-the-members-of-a-heap-allocated-class-automatically-allocated-in-the-hea), or [Class members allocation on heap/stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820477/class-members-allocation-on-heap-stack-c), or probably many more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But also, the array is allocated on the stack (no new operator)

No, the array is a member of the object. It's a part of it. If the object is dynamically allocated, then all of its parts are too.

Note I said all of **its** parts. We can tweak your example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    char *p_array;
};

int main()
{
    char array[10];
    MyClass *p = new MyClass{array};

    // Other code
}
```

Now the object contains a pointer. The pointer, being a member of the object, is dynamically allocated. But the address it holds, is to an object with automatic storage duration (the array).

Now, however, the array is no longer part of the object. That disassociation is what makes the layout you had in mind possible.

Answer (score 4):

What `MyClass *p = new MyClass;` really means is that you want to allocate `sizeof(MyClass)` bytes on the heap/free store to store every member of `MyClass`. The size of a class is based on it's members. `array` is a member of `MyClass` and thus because `MyClass` is allocated on the free store, so is `array`.