# Copy constructor demo (crashing... case 2)

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Please have a glance at this program:

```
class CopyCon
{
public:
char *name;

CopyCon()
{ 
    name = new char[20];        
    name = "Hai";//_tcscpy(name,"Hai");
}

CopyCon(const CopyCon &objCopyCon)
{
    name = new char[_tcslen(objCopyCon.name)+1];
    _tcscpy(name,objCopyCon.name);
}

~CopyCon()
{
    if( name != NULL )
    {
        delete[] name;
        name = NULL;
    }
}
};

int main()
{
    CopyCon obj1;
    CopyCon obj2(obj1);
    cout<<obj1.name<<endl;
    cout<<obj2.name<<endl;
}
```

This program crashes on execution. Error: "Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)"

If I assign "Hai" to name using aasignment operator, its crashing. Where as when I use string func _tcscpy to assign "Hai" to name, its working perfectly. Can some one explain why so?

Comment: It's kind of funny how only 10k reputation users post an answer to your problem. And basically they all say the same. Does that mean that one gets access to higher level knowledge when reaching 10k reputation?

Comment: You don't need to check for null before delete. passing NULL to delete is OK.

Comment: Why are you using `_tcslen` and `_tcscpy` with a `char` array?

Comment: Same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255612/c-dynamically-allocating-an-array-of-objects/255744#255744 Basically use a std::string rather than do memory management yourself.

Comment: Joe Gauterin: _tcslen() and _tcscpy() are not functions, but macros aliases for the versions of these functions that match your program's default character set, as determined by whether or not _UNICODE and/or _MBCS are #defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the default constructor

```
CopyCon()
{ 
    name = new char[20];        
    name = "Hai";//_tcscpy(name,"Hai");
}
```

you assign the address of a string literal to the pointer and in the destructor you call `delete[]` on it, that's undefined behavior. `delete[]` should only be called on addresses returned by `new[]`.

When you instead use `_tcscpy()` you copy the literal content to the buffer allocated by `new[]` and then the destructor runs fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
 name = "Hai";//_tcscpy(name,"Hai");
```

You are not copying contents of "Hai" into `name` instead `name` will point to a read only memory ( whose contents are "Hai")
if you try to delete name later then it *might* crash.

Comment: There is no more to say here.

Comment: Except that C++ makes no guarantee that "Hai" is stored in read-only memory.

Comment: It makes a guarantee that calling delete[] on a string literal results uin undefined behaviour though.

Answer (score 2):

When you use assignment, you make the pointer `name` point at the string literal "Hai". This later gets deleted in the destructor. However, the string literal was not allocated with `new`, and cannot be deleted like this, so you get undefined behaviour. You can only deallocate with `delete` things you allocated with `new`. This has nothing to do with the copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
name = new char[20];        
name = "Hai";//_tcscpy(name,"Hai");
```

Here you are *not* copying the data into the memory allocated by `new`. Instead you are assigning a new value to pointer `name` which points at read-only location (in most cases). Since this memory was not allocated using `new` you can not do `delete` on it. Also, note that you have a memory leak here as the memory allocated using `new char[20];` is never deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The very same program, but in C++:

```
struct CopyCon
{
  CopyCon(): name("HAI") {}
  std::string name;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  CopyCon obj1;
  CopyCon obj2(obj1);
  cout<<obj1.name<<endl;
  cout<<obj2.name<<endl;
}
```

Mine works, is clear, and I typed less than you did ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you do in that code is that you allocate a memory block for the name (assign an address to name pointer). Then you actually overwrite this address by the address of the string literal "Hai" (which ceases to exist after the constructor finishes). Thats why you get the error, since the destructor tries to free memory which does not belong to you. ( You did not allocate it ).