# C++: What is the proper way of resizing a dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++, arrays, resize

In C, I would have done it using `realloc`.

In C++, one would normally consider using the STL `vector` class.

But how do I properly resize an array in C++ without using any of the above solutions?

Comment: The proper way to resize a dynamically allocated array in C++ _is_ using a vector. Please tell us you objections to vector (and realloc), so we can respect these in the answers.

Comment: see [c-dynamically-allocating-an-array-of-objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255612/c-dynamically-allocating-an-array-of-objects/255744#255744)

Answer (score 8):

There is no good equivalent of `realloc` in C++.  You'll need to manually duplicate the array and copy the old elements over.  Fortunately, thanks to the `std::copy` function in `<algorithm>`, this isn't too bad:

```
size_t k =  /* ... */
T* buffer = /* .. get old buffer of size k. .. */

T* newBuffer = new T[newSize];  // Assume newSize >= k
std::copy(buffer, buffer + k, newBuffer);

delete [] buffer;
buffer = newBuffer;
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Reordered the last two lines!  Whoops!

Comment: @Nawaz- Whoops!  That was silly of me.  I just updated the code so that it doesn't do that anymore.

Comment: -1 Incorrect "There is no good equivalent of `realloc` in C++". C++ includes (most of) the C standard library. Including `realloc`.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach- That's true, but `realloc` is only safe with POD types.  If you try `realloc`ing an array of `string`, `vector`, etc. the results are undefined.  I probably should have said that there is no good **general** replacement for `realloc`.

Answer (score 3):

By doing what vector and realloc do internaly: make a new, bigger array, copy the content of the old one, and destroy the old one.

Answer (score 0):

```
int* arr = new int[20];
...
//wanna resize to 25?
int* temp = new int[25];
std::copy(arr, arr+20, temp);
delete [] arr;
arr = temp;
... //now arr has 25 elements
```

But, of course, you shouldn't do this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing this yourself in C++, you *probably* want to do roughly like `std::vector` does, and allocate raw memory using the global new operator, then use placement new to create objects "in place".

Otherwise, you end up constructing objects in all the memory you allocate, and then assigning over them when you use them. Unless you *know* that the initial (default) object construction is lightweight, you'd rather avoid it if possible.