# Understanding pointers and bad memory allocation?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, exc-bad-access, dynamic-arrays

**Disclaimer**: I am very very very new to C++. I took one class two years ago, and I'm taking another class now, so trying to get back into the mindset is tough. That being said, I know my code is extremely bad; I would like help and constructive criticism, so please avoid outright bashing, because I know I don't really know what I'm doing.

**Objective**: I'm writing a program that takes in two user-input sets of the form {1 2 3} (any size), and performs some operations on them. But I'm having trouble simply reading them in. Here is a quick snippet of the header file that shows what functions I'll be asking about:

```
class Set{

  public:

    Set();                  //Constructor for empty set.
    Set(int element);       //Constructor for set of one element
    ~Set();

    unsigned int getSize() const;                          
    int operator[](const int e) const;  

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& oss, const Set& output);   
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& ss, Set& target);         

  private:

    int size;
    int *elements[];        
    void resize(unsigned int new_size);
};
```

There's more, but I'm just showing you all what's necessary.

For the assignment, we create a class called Set, but the set must be stored as an array. We have an array of pointers for each Set (i.e. the Set class comes with int *elements[]). We need to overload the ">>" operator to convert the user-input to a Set. The user inputs *two* sets. We are assuming the user is smart enough to type it in in the exact form {1 2 3 4}, but it can be any size. Here is my overloaded >>.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& ss, Set& target){ 

  //The constructor Set target; creates an empty Set with array size=0.

  char c;      

  if (ss.peek()=='}') ss >> c; 
  if (ss.peek()==EOF) ss >> c;

  ss >> c;     //First we read in the '{' character.
  int num;

  while (ss.peek()!='}'){
    ss >> num;
    target.resize(target.getSize()+1); 
    *target.elements[target.getSize()-1]=num;
  };
  return ss;
};
```

getSize() is simply a function that returns the value "size." The goal of the above snippet is to create an empty Set, then for every int that is between "{" and "}", we resize the array by 1, then put that int into the next element of the array. Also, streams are still as abstract to me as pointers, so that's why this seems a little brute-force.

**The problem** I am having is with resize. I want--obviously--for resize to change the size, but it does not allow this. What I am trying to accomplish is for resize to change the called Set's *elements pointer to point to a new array with new_size number of elements. Then I want to deallocate that pointer to avoid memory leaks.

```
void Set::resize(unsigned int new_size){

  if (size!=new_size){
      int *newelements = new int[new_size];

      for (int i=0; i<new_size || i<size; i++){
          newelements[i] = *elements[i]; 
      };

      *elements = newelements;
      delete newelements;

      if (size>new_size) size=new_size;
   };

};
```

**One thing I know is wrong**: when I call newset.resize in the definition for ">>", the

```
newelements[i] = *elements[i];
```

line is trying to assign something that doesn't exist yet since "num" hasn't yet been assigned to *newset.elements[i]. However, if I try switching the order of these in ">>" so that it goes like this instead...

```
*target.elements[target.getSize()]=num;
target.resize(target.getSize()+1);
```

...this shouldn't make sense because the size of target's array is 0, so I can't say target[0]=num;

**Another thing I know is wrong**: Something *must* be wrong with the way I'm using the pointers because if I try to say size=new_size in the resize definition, I get the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error. Actually, if I run this as is, I get the same error message.

Additionally, in the assignment, we are told that "resize should only update size if new_size is strictly smaller than size." I don't understand how this can ever work. If we have to start with an initialized array of size=0, then how can we ever make it bigger?

I hope I have included enough to get a little help on this. I appreciate anything that would help me understand pointers and how to use them. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I picked up everything, but scanning through the code:

1. The declaration `int *elements[];` is illegal in C++ although some compilers allow it as an extension. **You must specify the array size.**
   If I compile with gcc, it tells me:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'elements' [-Wpedantic]
>
> int *elements[];
>   
>   
>   2. The line `if (size!=new_size)` is true always unless `size` does not equal `new_size`.
>      Most likely you want to resize the array only when `new_size` is **greater** than `size`.

3. `i<new_size || i<size` should probably be just `i<size`.

4. In `newelements[i] = *elements[i];`, the `*elements[i]` is equivalent to `*(elements[i])` and **not** `(*elements)[i]`, are you sure that is what you want?

5.

```
*elements = newelements;
delete newelements;
```

The first line makes the first element (a pointer) of `elements` to point at the newly allocated memory. The second line then **deletes** that memory, so now the first element of `elements` is now pointing at deallocated memory. That is not what you want.
Remember, when you assign a pointer to a pointer, it makes both pointers point at the same memory. What you will need to do is delete the **old** memory and then assign the pointer to point at the newly allocated memory.

6. Also remember that `delete []` is different from `delete`. You will need to use `delete []` when deleting the block of memory.

And hopefully this is all for learning purposes. In real C++ code, you would be using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks for your help!
1. Ah! I had forgotten that int *elements[] was absolutely illegal. I meant to have something like *elements[size], but I know that size must be declared at compile time, so that's why I removed it to work on later (and forgot about it).

   2./3. The size thing is part of the assignment: "If size matches new_size, then do nothing." Also, it makes sense to to resize it only when new_size>size, but the assignment says "resize should only update size if new_size is strictly smaller than size." This is another frustration that makes no intuitive sense to me.

Comment: @ErikaH: BTW there [are plenty of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371162/c-what-is-the-proper-way-of-resizing-a-dynamically-allocated-array) which already show you how to resize an array if you do some searching. Are you sure you even need an array of pointers? It looks like just you just want a dynamic array and you `Set` class has even more problems, search for "the rule of three C++" to learn more. Also `resize should only update size if new_size is strictly smaller than size` doesn't make sense (unless you want to shrink the array), that probably is a typo.

Comment: Also, just noticed `if (ss.peek()==EOF) ss >> c;` is unnecessary. If you reach `EOF`, then you cannot read anything more from the stream.

Comment: The assignment does strictly ask for an array of pointers, and it is about learning "The Big Three."

Comment: @ErikaH: In that case, you need to define a proper destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator. Also, if you are using C++11, you will need to add move operations also.

Comment: I know; that is also part of the assignment, but I chose not to include it here. Also, I got it to work. I took your advice, made int *elements;, then dynamically allocated space as per your advice. For example, for the Set with one element: elements=new int[1]; elements[0]=element; size=1;. I removed all those complicated pointers where they weren't necessary and it worked. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: np, remember to select this as the answer if it answered your questions.