# memory deallocation problem of an object

Tags: c++, c++11

I hava a class

```
class vlarray {
public:
    double *p;
    int size;

    vlarray(int n) {
        p = new double[n];
        size = n;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            p[i] = 0.01*i;
    }

    ~vlarray() {
        cout << "destruction" << endl;
        delete [] p;
        size = 0;
    }
};
```

when I use in main

```
int main() {
    vlarray a(3);
    {
        vlarray b(3);
        b.p[0] = 10;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cout << *(b.p+i) << endl;
        }
        a = b;
    }    // the magic happens here deallocation of b
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << *(a.p+i) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when b deallocated smth happens to a .. what is the problem, why that problem occurs and how to avoid such type of problems?

Comment: Sorry to be an ass, but if you can't be bothered to write words out in full with capital letters and full stops, then I can't be bothered to spend time helping you for free.

Comment: This may help; http://stackoverflow.com/q/255612/14065

Comment: @Tux: Good link. In fact I'm even tempted to call it a dup.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal : I am writing in lower because I used to do that &&  the reason I am not writing full stops because these days I am working on a project where words inserted in lower character && without any punctuations

Comment: @nurmurat: On Stack Overflow?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal : on localhost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>There seems to be some confusion amongst the existing answers on this question, so I *am* going to jump in.</sub>

---

#### Immediate issue

Your primary issue is that you have not defined your own **copy assignment operator**. Instead, the compiler generates a naive one for you, so that when you run `a = b`, the pointer inside `b` is copied into `a`. Then, when `b` dies and its destructor runs, the pointer now inside `a` is no longer valid. In addition, `a`'s original pointer has been leaked.

Your own copy assignment operator will need to `delete` the existing array, allocate a new one and copy over the contents from the object you're copying..

#### More generally

Going further, you will also need to define a few other things. This requirement is neatly summed-up as the [**Rule of Three** (C++03)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) or [**Rule of Five** (C++11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c0x), and there are plenty of explanations online and in [your favourite, peer-recommended C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that will teach you how to go about satisfying it.

#### Or, instead...

Better still, you could start using an `std::vector` instead of manually allocating everything, and avoid this entire mess:

```
struct vlarray {
    std::vector<double> p;

    vlarray(int n) {
        p.resize(n);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            p[i] = 0.01*i;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to follow the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)** in C++03  and  **[Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c0x)** in C++11.

**Background and Basis of these Rules:**

Whenever your class has an pointer member with an dynamic memory allocation, and whenever another object is created from this existing object by using any of the **Copying Functions**(Copy constructor & Copy Assignment Operator *in c++03*) unless you overload these two make a **Deep Copy** of the member pointer, the newly created object will keep pointing to the memory allocation of the parent object(**Shallow Copy**). The problem occurs when the parent object gets destroyed( for ex: by going out of scope) it's destructor gets called, which usually would free the memory allocated to the pointer member, When this happens the objects with a shallow copy of this pointer now point to invalid memory region and become **Dangling Pointers**. These dangling pointers when accessed result in Undefined Behavior and most likely crashes.

To avoid this you need to follow the Rule of Three in C++03 and Rule of Five in C++11.
The difference of Rules in C++03 and C++11 because the functions that control the copying behavior for a class have changed in C++11.

Rule of Three Basically states:
Implement the **copy constructor**, **copy assignment operator** and **Destructor** for your class.

EDIT:
If you are using C++11, then the Rule of Three actually becomes **[Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c0x)**.

Comment: This post is tagged `c++11`, which means that [the "Rule of Five" is more appropriate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c0x).

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Ah right, I missed the C++11 tag, I edited to reflect that, Thanks for noticing that detail.

Answer (score 0):

What you didn't implement is called:

- [Rule of three (C++ programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

which in short says,

> The rule of three (also known as the Law of The Big Three or The Big Three) is a rule of thumb in C++ that claims that if a class defines one of the following it should probably explicitly define all three:
>
> 1. destructor
> 2. copy constructor
> 3. copy assignment operator

Since you tagged your question `C++11` as well, then you have to implement this:

- [Rule of Five (in C++11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c0x)

Comment: This post is tagged `c++11`, which means that [the "Rule of Five" is more appropriate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c0x).

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Thanks. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't have a copy constructor. The compiler tried to do its best but it doesn't always succeed. Write a copy constructor and try again.

Comment: Actually the issue is a missing user-defined assignment operator (though a copy constructor would be wise too). And the compiler doesn't "try to do" or "fail" at anything: what is happening is completely well-defined up until the OP decides to `delete` the same block of memory twice.

Comment: -_- copy constructor would work ... don't have to -1 me.  You are right though an operator is what should be defined.

Comment: No, a copy constructor does not fix this problem, as `a=b` invokes the assignment operator, not the copy constructor. That's why you got a -1.

Answer (score 0):

The destruction of `b` caused the member pointer `p` to be deleted. Since this pointer was copied to `a`, the member pointer of `a` is now pointing to deleted memory. You have undefined behavior.

To avoid this you need to do a [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_copy#Deep_copy) at any point where you copy one object to another, typically the copy constructor and assignment operators. Allocate a new array and copy all the elements from one array to the other. You now adhere to the [Rule Of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) because you've already defined a destructor.

The best way around this problem is to avoid raw pointers altogether and replace them with `std::vector`.

Comment: Op needs to implement **Rule of Three** to be precise.

Comment: @Als: No; the OP needs to implement the **Rule of Five**.

Comment: You can't get to 5 without going through 3, so you're both right.

Comment: @Mark: I think you meant assignment operator.

Comment: @Tomalak, I've edited to reflect that both the copy constructor and assignment operator need to be defined. And I'd say the "Rule of Five" is more a "Suggestion of Five" since things still work properly in the absense of the new functions.

Answer (score -1):

Direct asignment shares `P` between instances. Create a copy constructor.

Comment: Op needs to implement **Rule of Three** to be precise.

Comment: @Als: Incorrect. It's the **Rule of Five** for C++11.

Comment: @robermorales: `a=b` does not invoke a copy constructor.

Answer (score -1):

When you assign b to a (a=b) the the compiler gerneated copy constructor does a shallow copy on your data members. I does not deference the pointers. So they both share the same resource, and when either of them are destroyed then they take their shared resource with them

Either define your own copy constructor to do a deep copy, or use an array abstraction like vector.

```
class vlarray {
public:
  std::vector<double> p;
  int size;
  vlarray(int n) {
    p.resize(n);
    size = n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) p[i] = 0.01*i;
  }
  ~vlarray() {
    cout << "destruction" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: No, `a=b` does not invoke a copy constructor.

Comment: It invokes copy assignment operator :)