# Reseting object m_object = Object(new, parameters);

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have a simple class:

```
class Histogram {
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
    int m_sampleSize;
    int m_bufferWidth;
    int m_bufferHeight;

    uint8* m_buffer;
    int m_size;
public:
    Histogram() : m_buffer(0) { }
    Histogram(int width, int height, int sampleSize) {
        m_buffer = new unsigned char [width*height*sampleSize];
    }
    ~Histogram() {
        my_log("destructor: buffer: %p", m_buffer);
        if ( m_buffer ) { delete [] m_buffer; m_buffer = NULL; }
    }
    unsigned char* buffer() {
        return m_buffer;
    }
};
```

It is a member in other class:

```
class Other {
    Histogram m_histogram;

    void reset() {
        my_log("reset() called: buffer: %p", m_histogram.buffer());
        m_histogram = Histogram(512, 512, 2);
    }
}
```

Now, I first create "uninitialized" object using Histogram() constructor – which sets m_buffer to NULL;

Then, I call the reset method, which does m_histogram = Histogram( 512, 512, 3 ) – the new object has m_buffer initialized via new.

So expected sequence of log messages is:

- "reset() called: buffer: 0x0"
- "destructor: buffer: 0x0"

But instead, I get:

- "reset() called: buffer: 0x0"
- "destructor: buffer: 0x072a7de"

So some irrational action is being performed. Moreover, the 0x072a7de address is displayied when I also delete the second object (created with "larger" constructor, with three int parameters).

Comment: The default copy constructor and assignment operator generated by the compiler does not behave nicely with pointers. You need to obey the `rule of three` (or five in C++11) see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/255744/14065

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you are pointing to a dynamically allocated array, you need to use operator `delete[]`

```
delete[] m_buffer;
```

Second, and more importantly, since you have dynamically allocated memory, you should follow the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) and implement a copy constructor, and assignment operator, as well as fixing the destructor.

What happens now is that your (compiler synthesized) assignment operator is making a "shallow" copy, i.e. it is copying the pointer. Then you will hve multiple destructors trying to delete it. You are invoking undefined behaviour.

You could really save yourself a lot of trouble by using an `std::vector<uint8>` as a buffer.

Comment: Sorry, in oryginal code I did use delete[]. As for the rest, I thought that following sequence will occur: a) delete old m_histogram, b) construct new Histogram(512, ...), c) copy it to space used by m_histogram. It could also create new histogram in the old space directly. Your answer states, that a) is done as last step?

Comment: @GameTCoder the RHS of your expression creates the new Histogram, but the assignment operator is used to assign to the LHS. This just makes a shallow copy of the RHS's pointer. The RHS is a temporary and gets deleted, so you are left with a dangling pointer in the LHS.

Comment: Thanks! This explains the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You MUST realize copy-ctor and assignment operator for your class Histogram, since

```
m_histogram = Histogram(512, 512, 2);
```

is assignment operator call. Implicit operator = bitwise copy members of your class.

And you must use `delete[]` in destructor, not `delete`, since you allocate an array.