# double free or corruption (runs ok if reorder lines)

Tags: c++

Use example in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063791/double-free-or-corruption-but-why), but change to use `char *` and `vector`:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Test{
    char *myArray;

public:
    Test(){
        myArray = new char[10];
    }

    ~Test(){
        delete[] myArray;
    }   
};  


int main(){
    vector<Test> q; // line 1
    Test t;         // line 2
    q.push_back(t);
}
```

It will cause double free or corruption error. However, if run line 2 before line 1, like:

```
Test t;
vector<Test> q;
```

Then it runs ok. Why is that?

Tested on Xubuntu 12.04 g++ 4.6.3.

Updated:

It's not duplicate question. I understand a copy constructor and an assignment operator are needed (it's already answered in the above link where the sample code is from). However, using `int *` or `queue` like that in the original link, but swapping line 1 and line 2, there is still error. Only using `char *`, and `vector` and swapping line 1 and line 2 will not cause error. My question is why is this particular case? Can anyone check it in your platform?

Comment: Yeah, `::std::shared_ptr` comes to mind, but you need to provide a custom deleter for arrays.

Comment: As I said in my answer, it is *undefined behaviour*. So all kinds of strange stuff can happen, including the code seeming to work.

Answer (score 8):

Your type manages resources (a dynamically allocated array) but does not implement the [*rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). When you do this:

```
q.push_back(t);
```

`q` makes a copy of `t`, which it owns. So now you have two copies of an object referring to the same data, and attempting to call `delete` in it.

You need to implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator. Or use a class that manages its own resources, such as `std::string` or `std::vector`.

Calling `delete[]` on an already deleted array is *undefined behaviour* (UB). This means that sometimes your program might *seem* to work. You cannot rely on a program with undefined behaviour to do anything. Swapping lines 1 and 2 inverts the order in which `t` and `q` get destroyed. This seems to yield a different result on your platform, but both are UB.

Comment: But why does instantiating the `Test` object before the `vector` hide the issue?

Comment: @Groo It is undefined behaviour, so it can seem to "work".

Answer (score 3):

C++ automatically makes a shallow copy of your `Test` object when you `push` it to the vector. When the vector goes out of scope and is destructed, the `myArray` pointer is `delete[]`d. Then, when Test goes out of scope, the same pointer is `delete[]`d again.

You should specify a [copy constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/) and make a deep copy of the object. Along with a new array.

Overloading assignment operator (explained in the same link as above) is also strongly suggested.

Comment: The only thing that is strongly suggested is using `std::vector<char>` or `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` instead of implementing everything yourself. The latter requires more effort for no reason and leads to error-prone and duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of three (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).  There is likely an assignment going on that you don't see between two `Test` objects, so the old pointer from one object is being naively assigned to the new object.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need a copy constructor.

`push_back` copies the argument and as you haven't provided a copy constructor, there's a default one, making a shallow copy (*copy just the pointer, without the content* *)

So, you need to define a

```
Test( const Test& other )
{
    // ...
}
Test& operator=( const Test& other ) // just in case
{
    // ...
}
```

and make a deep copy, manually copying the `char*` buffer.

*) which leads to double deletion - once from the `t`'s destructor, once from the `q`'s destructor (which calls the destructors of all elements in the vector)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Test objects are automatically created and deleted when managed by vector and when they are inserted by push_back. Imagine that when new elements are added to the vector, more space is needed and allocated and the existing elements are copied to new addresses. Which means they are are deleted and their dynamic memory deallocated. To be able to overcome this, define copy constructor for your class that will make a deep copy of the object. Or use smart pointers such as unique_ptr or shared_ptr (from boost or C++11).