# C++ pointers and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have a problem with dynamic array.

In header file class i have this:

```
class CTerrain
{
    ...
    CRock *rocks;
int numRocks;//=0
    ...
}
```

and in cpp i have this:

```
void CTerrain::Create()
{
    numRocks = 0;
    int NUM_ROCKS = rand()%10+1;
        for(int i=0;i<NUM_ROCKS;i++)
        {
            rocks = new CRock;
            numRocks++;
            ...
        }
 }
 void CTerrain::Render()
 {
     for(int i=0;i<numRocks;i++)
     rocks[i].render();//it works ok when here is 0 instead of 'i'
 }
```

When I run this code I got error:
Unhandled exception at 0x00913aea in OpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x1c00001f.

Thanks for any help, I have been trying to resolve this problem for like 4 hours...

EDIT:

Ok, so I changed Create() method to this:

```
void CTerrain::Create()
{
    numRocks = 0;
    int NUM_ROCKS = rand()%10+1;
    rocks = new CRock[NUM_ROCKS];
        for(int i=0;i<NUM_ROCKS;i++)
        {
        rocks[i].position = ...
            numRocks++;
            ...
        }
```

and also added delete [] rocks and now it's working.

Comment: I still have error after changing to "CRock **rocks". Now it shows up in line: "rocks[i] = new CRock;" Error: Unhandled exception at 0x00293b7a in OpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcdcdcdcd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, rocks **is pointer to** CRocks. Your implemenation: 
 rocks[i].render() should be something like this:

rocks = new CRock [x]; (where x is the number of objects of type CRock.)

rocks[i] -> render().

delete rocks[i]  // Just be sure to delete.

You may want to reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255612/dynamically-allocating-an-array-of-objects) for your solution on handling how a dynamic array of objects.

This other [reference](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~jestes/cop3330/notes/dma.html) is good.

Comment: Can it be 'delete [] rocks' or it must bo 'delete rocks[n]'?

Comment: delete [] will delete the entire array. delete rocks[i] will delete just the element 'ith'.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Create` function would  be more like

```
void CTerrain::Create()
{
    int NUM_ROCKS = rand()%10+1;
    rocks = new CRock[NUM_ROCKS];
    numRocks = NUM_ROCKS;
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_ROCKS; i++)
    {
        rocks[i] = CRock{};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add bit of explanation to above answer. Here:

```
 for(int i=0;i<NUM_ROCKS;i++)
 {
            rocks = new CRock;
            numRocks++;
            ...
 }
```

What you do is, each time assign *new* instance of `CRock` to the pointer `rock`; thereby losing reference to the old object and creating memory leaks. Use a solution similar suggester by Cyber.

Answer (score 0):

```
rocks = new CRock;
```

you overwrite `CRock*` pointer rocks in this line over and over again

Use this

`rocks = new CRock[NUM_ROCKS];`