# C++ how to add an element to a pointer array by exceeding size

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, memory-management

assume that we created dynamically allocated memory such as:

```
int SIZE = 10;
int *p = new int[SIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
  p[i] = i;
```

it will assing 0 to 9 to our pointer array.
Then i wanted to add 10,11,12 to the array
**can i do :**

```
p[10] = 10;
p[11] = 11;
p[12] = 12;
```

**or should i do:**

```
delete[] p;
size = 13;
p = new int[SIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
  p[i] = i;
```

Comment: Since this is `C++`, why don't you use a `vector<int>` directly?

Comment: That's nowhere near helpful. I think if the question involved using an array, that advice is good as an "also ..." side answer, but this question is very specificly about dynamic arrays. SO is earning its stereotype right now.

Comment: To resize an array you have to allocate a new array and copy the old elements to the new array, then delete the old array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238712/change-array-size-c

Comment: No, you can't append to an array by writing out of bounds. You have to create a new one. Unless you want some practice on `new`/`delete`, use a `std::vector`.

Comment: @sweenish -- The comment section is for comments, not answers.  I see nothing wrong with commenting on why `vector` is not used.

Comment: You must resize your array of course; otherwise you'll overflow it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Comments are for seeking clarifying information, and shouldn't be used for throwaway advice that is unrelated to the question. I feel that advice is unrelated because this is a very specific question about dynamic arrays. Students learning data structures need to know how to use them properly, so just blanket recommending a vector whenever a C-array is seen is just getting ridiculous.

Comment: @mfnx: In C++, is there no immediate way to reallocate, similar to realloc() in C?

Comment: @machine_1 - Only if the memory has been allocated using `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`.   But usage of those functions (from C) is discouraged in C++, for various reasons - in particular, it gives undefined behaviour is used to allocate memory for C++ class types that have a non-trivial constructor or destructor.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's a bold assumption, and a poor way to justify it. It's not like I said to never recommend vectors. I think the blanket recommendation at the sight of a C-array with no attempt at the real question is never helpful, comment or no. Just look at Mark Ingram's answer as something I believe to be an appropriate way to do this.

Comment: @machine_1 no, neither there should be. A realloc() would do just that: reallocating the memory. But in C++ there are more things to do, like calling the destructor on the old object.

Comment: @machine_1 You can use realloc if you please. As far as I know there is no equivalent in C++. I think "using std::vector" is a very good suggestion here.

Comment: @sweenish No it is not a bold assumption.  There have been many posts where the programmer was not aware of vector, or `std::list`, or some other C++ class or function, and were grateful that it was introduced to them in the comment section as a "why aren't you using x"?

Comment: @sweenish Ever heard of [xy problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Given this question in particular, it's a bold assumption.

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, I have. It doesn't change my opinion on how to go about recommending vectors.

Comment: @sweenish It is pretty common on SO to give additional advice in comments while not wanting (or being able) to write a full answer. We do not know the concrete scenario this question was asked for, especially we do not know if the question author is *forced* to use an array or if she/he might fall back to *better* alternatives. In the latter case, the vector advise *is* useful. And if none of the answers below would have mentioned it, the advice would be lost (be aware that the comment was posted before any of the answers).

Comment: @Aconcagua And as I said, I disagree. All the "this is justified" reasoning relies on heavy assumptions that I simply disagree with. I don't see a need to take this further.

Comment: @Aconcagua It's also common to give answers in comments. You only get in trouble when the OP is speaking a foreign language, though. If we're going to use "it's common" as a justification, there's no room for a rebuttal. Might as well have said, "It's whatever."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to reallocate memory for the array of a greater size. Otherwise the program will have undefined behavior.

For example

```
int SIZE = 10;
int *p = new int[SIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
  p[i] = i;

int *tmp = new int[SIZE + 3];

std::copy( p, p + SIZE, tmp );
delete []p;
p = tmp;

p[SIZE++] = 10;
p[SIZE++] = 11;
p[SIZE++] = 12;
```

Or instead of the last three statements you can write

```
for ( const int &value : { 10, 11, 12 } ) p[SIZE++] = value;
```

Of course in such cases it is better to use the standard container `std::vector`.

In fact the code above is similar to the following

```
#include <vector>

//...

std::vector<int> v( 10 );

for ( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) v[i] = i;

v.reserve( 13 );
for ( const int &value : { 10, 11, 12 } ) v.push_back( value );
```

except that all the memory management is done internally by the vector.

Comment: Is it wrong to shake in disgust when looking at `p[SIZE++]`?

Comment: As we are deleting the old array anyway, I'd prefer [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) over `std::copy` – while irrelevant for integers, it might make quite a difference for complex types (like `std::string`)...

Comment: @Aconcagua I agree with you.

Comment: Hm, not necessarily equivalent, the constructor might decide to reserve more elements right from the start, in which case re-allocation might not occur. And `std::vector` *would* move, if possible...

Answer (score 3):

The second option is the correct way. The first option won't always complain, but you are writing to memory that has not been set aside for your array; it has been set aside for something else, and you don't know what. Sometimes it will behave okay, sometimes it won't. Assigning to an array outside its range is Undefined Behavior, and we should avoid it.

Comment: Second option is wrong since it mixes `size` and `SIZE`.

Comment: I'm chalking that up to a simple typo, but it's good to bring up.

Answer (score 3):

In your first example suggestion:

```
p[10] = 10;
p[11] = 11;
p[12] = 12;
```

You will be overwriting memory that you don't own, which can lead to a crash. You need to reallocate your original array.

```
const int oldSize = SIZE;
SIZE = 13;
int *newP = new int[SIZE];
memcpy(newP, p, oldSize * sizeof(int));
for (int i = oldSize; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    newP[i] = i;
}

delete[] p;
p = newP;
```

Your second example would work, but is slightly less efficient, because you're re-calculating the values with each reallocation. In my example above, you only re-calculate the new values.

Alternatively, you should look at `std::vector` which is designed specifically for this purpose (a dynamically sizing array).

```
std::vector<int> p;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    p.push_back(i);
}
```

Here the `std::vector` manages the allocation internally, so you don't have to worry about `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Side note: `memcpy` usually is invalid if complex objects are involved (like `std::string`). For consistency, I'd then avoid `memcpy` even for types where it actually is allowed in favour of the C++ means like `std::copy`.

Comment: Yep I agree, the original intention of my answer was to preserve the "style" of the question (i.e. raw pointers and manual memory management), but yes, the memcpy should be discouraged.