# error: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)" when i try to insert class objects in array of class objects c++

Tags: c++, arrays

So i have created a class that creates an array of objects from another class and when i try to execute the program and insert new objects to the array i get this error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
Specifically on the insertion of the 10th element.

this is the class that has the array:

```
class Savelist{
private:
     list_reserve *reserve;
     list_user *users;
     int length,MaxSize;
     string code;
public:
     string stoixeia;

     Savelist(int MaxListSize)
   {// Constructor for formula-based linear list.
    MaxSize = MaxListSize;
    reserve = new list_reserve (MaxSize, code);
    users=new list_user(MaxSize);
    length = 0;
    }
   ~Savelist() {delete [] reserve,delete [] users;} // destructor

   bool IsEmpty() const {return length == 0;}
   int Length() const {return length;}
```

the method that inserts class objects to array:

```
void Insert_flight(list_reserve input)
{// "push" all objects one position up
    if (length!=0)
    {
        for (int i=length-1; i >=0; i--)
        {
            reserve[i]=reserve[i+1];

        }
        reserve[0] = input;

        length++;
                }
    else
    {
        reserve[0] = input;
        length++;
    }
}
```

here is the class that creates the objects that are being inserted to array:

```
class list_reserve { 

private:
   bool result;
   int length,MaxSize;
   string *object; // dynamic 1D array

public:
   string code;
   bool get_result;

   // constructor
   list_reserve(int MaxListSize,string flcode)
   {// Constructor for formula-based linear list.
    MaxSize = MaxListSize;
    object = new string [MaxSize];
    length = 0;
    code=flcode;
    }

    ~list_reserve() {delete [] object;} // destructor

    bool IsEmpty() const {return length == 0;}
    int Length() const {return length;}
```

the method that inserts simple strings to the object of that class:

```
void Insert_User(string input,string code,list_flight schedule)
{// Insert user
    if (length!=0)
    {
        for (int i=length-1; i >=0; i--)
        {
            object[i+1] = object[i];

        }
        object[0] = input;
        schedule.Get(code);
        schedule.update(schedule.code, 1);
        length++;

    }
    else
    {
        object[0] = input;
        schedule.Get(code);
        schedule.update(schedule.code, 1);
        length++;

    }
}
};
```

And lastly the main():

```
   int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
       list_reserve  DA001_r(100,"DA001"),DA002_r(100,"DA002"),DA003_r(100,"DA003"),DA004_r(100,"DA004"),DA005_r(100,"DA005")        
,DA006_r(100,"DA006"),DA007_r(100,"DA007"),DA008_r(100,"DA008"),DA009_r(100,"DA009"),DA010_r(100,"DA010"),DA011_r(100,"DA011")
,DA012_r(400,"DA012"),DA013_r(400,"DA013"),DA014_r(100,"DA014"),DA015_r(100,"DA015"),DA016_r(100,"DA016"),DA017_r(100,"DA017")
,DA018_r(100,"DA018"),DA019_r(100,"DA029"),DA020_r(100,"DA020"),DA021_r(100,"DA021"),DA022_r(100,"DA022"),DA023_r(400,"DA023"),
DA024_r(400,"DA024");



Savelist Queues(100);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA001_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA002_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA003_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA004_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA005_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA006_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA007_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA008_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA009_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA010_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA011_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA012_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA013_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA014_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA015_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA016_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA017_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA018_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA019_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA020_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA021_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA022_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA023_r);
Queues.Insert_flight(DA024_r);


  }
```

Comment: use a debugger. Note that new and delete with raw owning pointers is not recommended.

Comment: Using `std::vector` instead of dynamically allocated arrays would probably fix most of your problems.

Comment: is it bad if i don't use the destructors at all??

Comment: @DionisisNikas yes.

Comment: can someone post an example of the code i would use with using 'std::vector' ?? Because i want to be able to search the vector and get the class objects i want based on their content and then use methods of the selected object.

Comment: thats why i chose dynamically allocated arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really, really don't want to store owning pointers to dynamically allocated resources in classes.  For a good rundown on why see [this answer on what's necessary to store an owning pointer in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255744/6145544).  Using a standard container such as `std::vector` also greatly simplifies the code as these implement most common operations you may want to do with them, such as insertion, deletion and the like.

For instance, your `Savelist` class would become the following when using `std::vector`

```
class Savelist {
private:
    vector<list_reserve> reserve;
    vector<list_user> users;
    // No need for storing MaxSize or length, std::vector can store any
    // number of elements, and knows how many elements it contains.
    string code;

public:
    string stoixeia;

    // constructor and destructor becomes unnecessary, as the vector member
    // takes care of all the bookkeeping

    bool IsEmpty() const { return reserve.empty(); }
    int Length() const { return reserve.size(); }

    // Insert flight need only pass the input to the vector
    void Insert_flight(list_reserve input) { reserve.insert(reserve.begin(), input); }
};
```

And similarly for the `list_reserve` class

```
class list_reserve { 
private:
   bool result;
   // once again, the vector keeps track of size and elements contained
   vector<string> object;

public:
    string code;
    bool get_result;

    // constructor becomes simpler
    list_reserve(string flcode)
    {
       code = flcode;
    }

    // destructor becomes unnecessary

    bool IsEmpty() const { return object.empty(); }
    int Length() const { return object.size(); }


    void Insert_User(string input, string code, list_flight schedule)
    {
        // note that object.push_back(input); would be
        // more efficient, but inserts the element at the end.
        object.insert(object.begin(), input);
        schedule.Get(code);
        schedule.update(schedule.code, 1);
    }
};
```

See also [cppreference page on `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for an excellent reference on what's available.

Comment: Huge thanks man thats really helpful !! How am i going to search for a specific object in saveclass though??

Comment: and also on list reserve when i use    'object.insert(0, input);' it pops an error that i am calling a private constructor

Comment: Ah right, it's `object.insert(object.begin(), input);`, strings allow indexing on numbers but not vectors and I forgot about that.  I've fixed the answer.  For finding an element you can use `std::find` from `<algorithm>` or write a for loop to iterate through the vector until you find what you're looking for.

Comment: if you can only answer me one more thing. After i use find to find the selected list_reserve object from the vector, how can i gain access to the methods of this objects class??