# C++: free(): double free detected in tcache 2 problem when merging two linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying merge two list in C++. My implementation are below:

listnode.h

```cpp
#ifndef __LISTNODE_H
#define __LISTNODE_H

template< class NODETYPE > class List;

template <class NODETYPE>
class ListNode
{
    friend class List< NODETYPE >;
private:
    NODETYPE data;
    ListNode* next;

public:
    ListNode(const NODETYPE &);
    ~ListNode() {};
    NODETYPE getData() const;
    ListNode<NODETYPE>* getNext() const;
};

template< class NODETYPE >
ListNode<NODETYPE>::ListNode(const NODETYPE& data)
    :data(data),
     next(0)
{ }  // empty ctor body

template< class NODETYPE >
NODETYPE ListNode<NODETYPE>::getData() const { return data; }

template< class NODETYPE >
ListNode<NODETYPE>* ListNode<NODETYPE>::getNext() const { return next; }

#endif
```

list.h

```cpp
#ifndef __LIST_H
#define __LIST_H

#include "listnode.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>

template <class NODETYPE>
class List
{
private:
    ListNode<NODETYPE>* firstPtr;
    ListNode<NODETYPE>* lastPtr;
    ListNode<NODETYPE>* getNewNode(const NODETYPE&);

public:
    List();
    ~List();
    void insertFromFront(const NODETYPE&);
    void insertAtBack(const NODETYPE&);
    bool removeFromFront(const NODETYPE&);
    bool removeFromBack(const NODETYPE&);
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void print() const;
    ListNode<NODETYPE>* getFirstNode() const;
    ListNode<NODETYPE>* getLastNode() const;
    void sort();
    void concatenate(List<NODETYPE>);
};

template< class NODETYPE >
List<NODETYPE>::List()
    : firstPtr(0),
      lastPtr(0)
{// empty ctor body}

template< class NODETYPE >
List<NODETYPE>::~List() {
    
    ListNode<NODETYPE> *iter = firstPtr, *temp;
    if(!isEmpty()) {
        while (iter) {
            temp = iter;
            iter = iter->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
}

template< class NODETYPE >
void List<NODETYPE>::insertFromFront(const NODETYPE& value) {

    ListNode<NODETYPE> *newNode = getNewNode(value);
    
    if (newNode) {
        if (isEmpty())
            firstPtr = lastPtr = newNode;
        else {
            newNode -> next = firstPtr; // newNode->next points whereever firstPtr points to.
            firstPtr = newNode;         // firstPtr now demonstrates the first nodeç
        }
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Allocation failed!" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

template< class NODETYPE >
void List<NODETYPE>::insertAtBack(const NODETYPE& value) {

    ListNode<NODETYPE> *newNode = getNewNode(value);
    if (newNode) {
        if(isEmpty())
            firstPtr = lastPtr = newNode;
        else {
            
            lastPtr -> next = newNode;
            lastPtr = newNode;
            
        }   
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Allocation fails!" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // terminate the program
    }
}

template< class NODETYPE >
bool List<NODETYPE>::removeFromFront(const NODETYPE& value) {

    ListNode<NODETYPE>* temp;
    
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    if(firstPtr == lastPtr) { // if only one node present
        value = firstPtr -> data;
        firstPtr = lastPtr = 0;
        return true;
    }

    temp = firstPtr;
    value = temp -> data;
    firstPtr = firstPtr -> next;
    delete temp;

    return true;

} 

template< class NODETYPE >
bool List<NODETYPE>::removeFromBack(const NODETYPE& value) {

    if (isEmpty())
        return false;
    
    if(firstPtr == lastPtr) { // if only one node present
        value = lastPtr->data;
        firstPtr = lastPtr = 0;
        return true;
    }

    ListNode<NODETYPE> *iter = firstPtr;
    while (iter != lastPtr)
        iter = iter->next;
    
    lastPtr = iter;             // alter the point lastPtr points to.
    value = iter->next->data;   // grab the value of last node
    delete iter->next;          // delete the last node
    
    return true;

}

template< class NODETYPE >
bool List<NODETYPE>::isEmpty() const {
    return firstPtr == 0;
}

template< class NODETYPE >
void List<NODETYPE>::print() const {
    ListNode<NODETYPE> *iter = firstPtr;
    while(iter) {
        std::cout << iter->data << ' ';
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}

template< class NODETYPE >
void List<NODETYPE>::sort() {
    NODETYPE min = firstPtr -> data;
    for (ListNode<NODETYPE>* i = firstPtr; i != 0; i = i -> next) {
        for (ListNode<NODETYPE>* j = i -> next; j != 0; j = j -> next) {
            if(j->data < i->data){
                NODETYPE temp = i->data;
                i->data = j->data;
                j->data = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

template< class NODETYPE >
ListNode<NODETYPE>* List<NODETYPE>::getNewNode(const NODETYPE &value) {
    return new ListNode<NODETYPE>(value);
}

template< class NODETYPE >
ListNode<NODETYPE>* List<NODETYPE>::getFirstNode() const { return firstPtr; }

template< class NODETYPE >
ListNode<NODETYPE>* List<NODETYPE>::getLastNode() const { return lastPtr; }

template< class NODETYPE >
void List<NODETYPE>::concatenate(List<NODETYPE> l) {
    
    ListNode<NODETYPE>* iter = l.getFirstNode(); // first node of the second linked list
    while (iter != 0){
        insertAtBack(iter->getData());
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    sort(); // to sort in ascending order
    //std::cout << "lastPtr->data:" << lastPtr->data << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "list.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

template < class NODETYPE>
List<NODETYPE> mergeHandler(List<NODETYPE> list1, List<NODETYPE> list2) {
    
    List<NODETYPE> resultList;
    NODETYPE min = list1.getFirstNode()->getData();
    for (ListNode<NODETYPE>* i = list1.getFirstNode(); i != 0; i = i -> getNext()) {
        
    }
    resultList.print();
    return resultList;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    List< int > intList1, intList2/*, mergedList*/;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        intList1.insertFromFront(1 + rand() % 100);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        intList2.insertFromFront(1 + rand() % 100);
    
    //intList1.print();
    //intList1.sort();
    intList1.print();

    //intList2.print();
    //intList2.sort();
    intList2.print();

    intList1.concatenate(intList2);
    intList1.sort();
    intList1.print();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, as mentioned, that at the end of the program, it yields

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I couldn't understand the problem. Because I created new nodes to the first list and add the values of the second list. So even if I delete the same values, I delete the values stored exactly different addresses. [In of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413418/free-double-free-detected-in-tcache-2), reccomends of implementing copy ctor and = operator. However, I couldn't get  and implement it because I use the normal constructor, but when I implement this ctor

```cpp
public:
.
.
.
List(List<NODETYPE> &rhs){std::cout << "Do nothing in copy ctor" << std::endl;}
```

It strangly outputs *Do nothing in copy ctor* even though I use the normal consturctor. How can I handle this issue? I have already a concatenate method and wanna use it, because when I use copy ctor, it throws a **segmentation fault** error.

Comment: @fabian, but how my head pointers are the same? I mean I use two different list and they are pointing the different addresses, aren't they? Lastly, as far as I understand, you suggestion throws more clear error, right?

Comment: Copy constructors take the argument by const reference, the constructor you've posted doesn't. Furthermore this "copy constructor" leaves all members uninitialized resuling in undefined behaviour, if one of the member variables is read which is always the case. You need to properly implement the copy constructor by copying node by node or at least pass the parameter of `concatenate` by reference to const and do the copying of nodes there; You should define the copy/move semantics as deleted in the latter case to prevent accidental copies.

Comment: do not use names beginning with underscores in your own code - they will almost certainly be reserved for the c++ implementation

Comment: @akoluaciklinux the implicitly defined copy/move constructors simply use the copy/move constructors for every non-static member variable and for pointers this means the pointer value is simply copied and you effectively get something like `ListNode<NODETYPE>* firstPtr1 = ...; /* copy ctor */ ListNode<NODETYPE>* firstPtr2 = firstPtr1; ... /* destructor second object */ delete firstPtr2; /* destructor first object */ delete firstPtr1;` resulting in delete being called twice for the same object. (I'm referring to the case where the additional constructor is missing here.)